# find duplicate, compare a condition, erase one row r

Tags: r, if-statement, duplicates

Using the following reproducible example:

```
ID1<-c("a1","a4","a6","a6","a5", "a1" )
ID2<-c("b8","b99","b5","b5","b2","b8" )
Value1<-c(2,5,6,6,2,7)
Value2<- c(23,51,63,64,23,23)
Year<- c(2004,2004,2004,2004,2005,2004)
df<-data.frame(ID1,ID2,Value1,Value2,Year)
```

I want to select rows where ID1 and ID2 and Year have the same value in their respective columns. For this rows I want to compare Value1 and Value2 in the duplicates rows and IF the values are not the same erase the row with the smaller value.

Expected result:

```
  ID1 ID2 Value1 Value2 Year         new

2  a4 b99      5     51 2004 a4_b99_2004

4  a6  b5      6     64 2004  a6_b5_2004
5  a5  b2      2     23 2005  a5_b2_2005
6  a1  b8      7     23 2004  a1_b8_2004
```

I tried the following:
Find a unique identifier for the conditions I am interested

```
df$new<-paste(df$ID1,df$ID2, df$Year, sep="_")
```

I can use the unique identifier to find the rows of the database that contain the duplicates

```
IND<-which(duplicated(df$new) | duplicated(df$new, fromLast = TRUE))
```

In a for loop if unique identifier has duplicate compare the values and erase the rows, but the loop is too complicated and I cannot solve it.

```
for (i in df$new) {

  if(sum(df$new == i)>1)
           {
  ind<-which(df$new==i)
  m= min(df$Value1[ind])
  df<-df[-which.min(df$Value1[ind]),]
  m= min(df$Value2[ind])
  df<-df[-which.min(df$Value2[ind]),]

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `aggregate` to retrieve the max values by your grouping, *ID1*, *ID2*, and *Year*:

```
df_new <- aggregate(.~ID1 + ID2 + Year, df, max)
df_new

#   ID1 ID2 Year Value1 Value2
# 1  a6  b5 2004      6     64
# 2  a1  b8 2004      7     23
# 3  a4 b99 2004      5     51
# 4  a5  b2 2005      2     23
```

Comment: Wow, very elegant solution! I hope to not forget this!!

Comment: only one caveat, it deletes rows with 'NA' hence I added 'na.action = na.pass'. BUT one problem still remain, it deletes rows were only one of the IDs has 'NA'

Comment: I posted another question to explain the problem with an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52814300/find-duplicate-compare-a-condition-erase-one-row-with-nas-r

Answer (score 2):

Some different possibilities. Using `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID1, ID2, Year) %>%
  filter(Value1 == max(Value1) & Value2 == max(Value2))
```

Or:

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(max_val = sum(Value1, Value2)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(ID1, ID2, Year) %>%
  filter(max_val == max(max_val)) %>%
  select(-max_val)
```

Using `data.table`:

```
setDT(df)[df[, .I[Value1 == max(Value1) & Value2 == max(Value2)], by = list(ID1, ID2, Year)]$V1]
```

Or:

```
setDT(df)[, max_val := sum(Value1, Value2), by = 1:nrow(df)
   ][, filter := max_val == max(max_val), by = list(ID1, ID2, Year)
       ][filter != FALSE
         ][, -c("max_val", "filter")]
```

Or:

```
subset(setDT(df)[, max_val := sum(Value1, Value2), by = 1:nrow(df)
             ][, filter := max_val == max(max_val), by = list(ID1, ID2, Year)], filter != FALSE)[, -c("max_val", "filter")]
```

Comment: Nice collection of methods, all of them just erase NAs...what if I want to consider them?

Comment: There are no NAs in your data, do you mean keeping cases that don't fulfill your criteria?

Comment: I did not put NAs in the example but I do have NAs in all the columns in my real data (not in Year).

Comment: For Value columns you can use max(Value, na.rm = TRUE) or you can replace your NAs with 0 (or with other value of choice). Assigning IDs is not a computational problem but a conceptual one.

Comment: I think that in this case it also a computational problem. If I change the NAs to a character string in the ID it has duplicates when in a year there are NA AND the real ring for one of the IDs. If I keep the NAs it deletes rings when one of the ID is NA.

Comment: That could be an issue worth of a separate question. Please consider posting it.

Comment: Good idea, if I do not solve it myself I will post an updated version.

Comment: I posted the following question to explain the problem (I used the aggregated solution but yours would have the same problem). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52814300/find-duplicate-compare-a-condition-erase-one-row-with-nas-r

Answer (score 0):

Solution without loading libraries:

```
            ID1 ID2 Value1 Value2 Year
a6.b5.2004   a6  b5      6     64 2004
a1.b8.2004   a1  b8      7     23 2004
a4.b99.2004  a4 b99      5     51 2004
a5.b2.2005   a5  b2      2     23 2005
```

#### Code

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, list(df$ID1, df$ID2, df$Year)),                  # make identifiers
                      function(x) {return(x[which.max(x$Value1 + x$Value2),])})) # take max of sum
```