# find duplicate, compare a condition, erase one row - with NAs R

Tags: r, if-statement, duplicates, aggregate

I am building upon this question [find duplicate, compare a condition, erase one row r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52803902/find-duplicate-compare-a-condition-erase-one-row-r)
to solve a more complicated case.

Using the following reproducible example:

```
ID1<-c("a1","a4","a6","a6","a5", "a1",NA,"a3", "a2","a2", "a8", "a9", "a9")
ID2<-c("b8","b99","b5","b5","b2","b8" , "b7","b7", "b6","b6",NA,"b9",NA)
Value1<-c(2,5,6,6,2,7, NA,5,NA,4,4,6,6)
Value2<- c(23,51,63,64,23,23,5,6,4,NA,NA,4,NA)
Year<- c(2004,2004,2004,2004,2005,2004,2008,2009, 2008,2009,2014,2016,2016)
df<-data.frame(ID1,ID2,Value1,Value2,Year)
```

I want to select rows where ID1 and ID2 and Year have the same value in their respective columns. For this rows I want to compare Value1 and Value2 in the duplicates rows and IF the values are not the same erase the row with within the column higher value (because of the data structure this will be unambiguous
).

Expected Results:

### Expected

```
#     ID1  ID2 Value1 Value2 Year
# 1    a1   b8      2     23 2004
# 2    a4  b99      5     51 2004
# 3    a6   b5      6     63 2004

# 5    a5   b2      2     23 2005

# 7  <NA>   b7     NA      5 2008
# 8    a3   b7      5      6 2009
# 9    a2   b6     NA      4 2008
# 10   a2   b6      4     NA 2009
# 11   a8 <NA>      4     NA 2014
# 12   a9   b9      6      4 2016
```

First solution:

```
df_new <- aggregate(.~ID1 + ID2 + Year, df, min, na.action = na.pass)
```

PROBLEM: it deletes raws when one of the IDs is NA

I then changed NAs to a character value

```
df$ID1[is.na(df$ID1)] <- "Missing_data"
df$ID2[is.na(df$ID2)] <- "Missing_data"

df_new <- aggregate(.~ID1 + ID2 + Year, df, min, na.action = na.pass)
```

I solve the previous problem but I create a second one.

PROBLEM: it has IDs duplicates when in a single year there are NA AND the ID for one of the IDs (last 2 lines in df)

Comment: When you say "erase the row with the smaller value" you mean `Value1` or `Value2`? Your expected output doesn't seem to match that description.

Comment: Also, why your last row with `ID1 = a9` and `ID2 = NA` is not in your expected output?

Comment: @AntoniosK thanks, I edited the text, I meant "higher value".  The last row is not in the expected output because is a duplicate of the previous one.

Comment: "Higher value" is meaningless when you have `Value1` and `Value2`, not a single `value`. If you have two rows identical except row A has `Value1 = 23` and `Value2 = 2`, and row B has `Value1 = 2` and `Value2 = 23`, do you want to keep row A or row B (and why)? Or do you want to mix and match rows, keeping the lower value in each column, ending up with `Value1 = 2` and `Value2 = 2`? (Which sounds a lot more like aggregating than removing duplicates.)

Comment: @Gregor thanks for your comment. I repharesed the question. The function min in aggregate does what I want for complete cases. The problem is on the comparisons that include NAs.

Comment: @havefun Your 2nd solution works fine, because the rows you want to exclude are not duplicates. `NA` is not the same as any of the other values you have. I uncerstand you want to exclude them, but you have to add to your process some other filters in order to do that.

Comment: @AntoniosK I want to exclude them because when plotting or analysing the data they would count twice. would you be able to help on the necessary filter to exclude them?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(Value2) %>%             
  distinct(ID1, ID2, Year, .keep_all = T) %>%    
  arrange(ID2) %>%
  distinct(ID1, Year, .keep_all = T) %>%  
  arrange(ID1) %>%
  distinct(ID2, Year, .keep_all = T)

#      ID1  ID2 Value1 Value2 Year
# 1    a1   b8      2     23 2004
# 2    a2   b6     NA      4 2008
# 3    a2   b6      4     NA 2009
# 4    a3   b7      5      6 2009
# 5    a4  b99      5     51 2004
# 6    a5   b2      2     23 2005
# 7    a6   b5      6     63 2004
# 8    a8 <NA>      4     NA 2014
# 9    a9   b9      6      4 2016
# 10 <NA>   b7     NA      5 2008
```

When we arrange by `Value2` the smaller values of `Value` will be on top and `distinct` will remove any duplicates and keep the 1st row it finds (i.e. the one with the smaller `Value2`).

When we arrange by `ID1` and then `ID2` the `NA` values will be on the bottom and `distinct` will exclude them if they are duplicates.

*Note* that I'm using only `Value2` to keep small values, as it's still not clear to me what you mean by "value".

Comment: Hi, I do not understand your Note. By value I mean smaller number. I want to have the comparison always within the same column of numbers (Value1 or Value2). The numbers between the 2 columns (Value1 and Value2) never need a comparison.

Comment: The solution does not work for  data with  multiple NAs because it keeps only one of them

Comment: You have to add an example like this in your post so i can update my answer. If the dataset you post is not representative of your real case there will be bugs.